# Java: LDAP Search returning 1 row

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap

I am trying to get all users from my active directory however my code is returning just one row. I have tried the below which is currently only outputting one user.

```
private void getUserBasicAttributes(String username, LdapContext ctx) {

    try {
        List<String> usersList = new ArrayList<String>();
        SearchControls constraints = new SearchControls();
        constraints.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);


        //First input parameter is search bas, it can be "CN=Users,DC=YourDomain,DC=com"
        //Second Attribute can be uid=username
         NamingEnumeration<SearchResult>  answer = ctx.search("DC=domain,DC=com", "(&(objectCategory=user))"
             , constraints);
        if (answer.hasMoreElements()) {
        Person person = new Person();
           SearchResult  attrs = ((SearchResult) answer.next());
            String names[] = attrs.getName().split(",");
                 String name[] = names[0].split("=");

            usersList.add(name[1]);


        }else{
            throw new Exception("Invalid User");
        }

        System.out.println(usersList.size());

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not looping over all the results, add a while loop inside the if

```
if (answer.hasMoreElements()) {
    while(answer.hasMoreElements()) {
        Person person = new Person();
        SearchResult  attrs = ((SearchResult) answer.next());
        String names[] = attrs.getName().split(",");
        String name[] = names[0].split("=");

        usersList.add(name[1]);
    }
}else{
    throw new Exception("Invalid User");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `while` instead of `if`:

```
while (answer.hasMoreElements()) {
    Person person = new Person();
    SearchResult  attrs = ((SearchResult) answer.next());
    String names[] = attrs.getName().split(",");
    String name[] = names[0].split("=");
    usersList.add(name[1]);
}
if (usersList.size() == 0) {
    throw new Exception("Invalid User");
}
```

You can simplify the name-element handling as well. No need to parse the DN. Just specify the attribute(s) you want returned up front and retrieve them directly.

Answer (score -1):

You are making this too hard. No reason to perform any "splitting" pf values.

```
// Specify the ids of the attributes to return
String[] attrIDs = { "uid" };

// Get ONLY the attributes desired
Attributes answer = ctx.getAttributes("CN=Users,DC=YourDomain,DC=com", attrIDs);
for (NamingEnumeration ae = answer.getAll(); ae.hasMore();) {
    Attribute attr = (Attribute)ae.next();
    System.out.println("attribute: " + attr.getID());
    /* Print each value */
    for (NamingEnumeration e = attr.getAll(); e.hasMore();
         System.out.println(e.next()))
        ;
}
```

Let me know how I can help.

Comment: There's no need for any of that either. If you're only retrieving one attribute, you can get it directly. No need to iterate over all 1 attributes. Doesn't answer the actual question that was asked.